# https://+:62545/ in OPC UA Empty Server - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server, opc

I've an exception (AddressAccessDeniedException) in OPC UA Empty Server (C#). This exception refer a problem with URL https://+:62545/.

Down the STACK TRACE:

> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
>
> in Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaHttpsChannelListener.Start() in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\OPC UA\Stack\Core\Stack\Https\HttpsListener.cs:riga 312
>
> in Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaHttpsChannelListener.Open(Uri baseAddress, TransportListenerSettings settings, ITransportListenerCallback callback) in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\OPC UA\Stack\Core\Stack\Https\HttpsListener.cs:riga 125
>
> in Opc.Ua.ServerBase.CreateHttpsServiceHost(IDictionary`2 hosts, ApplicationConfiguration configuration, BindingFactory bindingFactory, IList`1 baseAddresses, ApplicationDescription serverDescription, List`1 securityPolicies) in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\OPC UA\Stack\Core\Stack\Server\ServerBase.cs:riga 1174
>
> in Opc.Ua.Server.StandardServer.InitializeServiceHosts(ApplicationConfiguration configuration, BindingFactory bindingFactory, ApplicationDescription& serverDescription, EndpointDescriptionCollection& endpoints) in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\OPC UA\SampleApplications\SDK\Server\Server\StandardServer.cs:riga 2718
>
> in Opc.Ua.ServerBase.Start(ApplicationConfiguration configuration) in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\OPC UA\Stack\Core\Stack\Server\ServerBase.cs:riga 247
>
> in Opc.Ua.Configuration.ApplicationInstance.Start(ServerBase server) in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\OPC UA\SampleApplications\SDK\Configuration\ApplicationInstance.cs:riga 459
>
> in Quickstarts.EmptyServer.Program.Main() in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\OPC UA\SampleApplications\Workshop\Empty\Server\Program.cs:riga 78

Comment: when did you get this error.please post your code also.

Comment: The code is relating to Sample SDK of the Foundation: Empty Server.

Comment: Hello and and welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you very much for joing our commnuity. Could you please add some code. And what you allready tried ?

Comment: The code is in https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET/tree/master/SampleApplications/Workshop/Empty/Server. I haven't edited the source code.

Comment: The problem may be in the http://paste.ofcode.org/37EWH6W4K355AedWyRyBczL (Quickstarts.EmptyServer.Config.xml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to fix: Run command prompt as an administrator. Add the URL to the ACL

> netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:62545/ user=my_local_user.